# Unable to specify the 'where' parameter in call to Google Maps Engine

Tags: google-maps

I've been looking at the documentation for GME at https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/public-read and I am unable to get a valid read if I specify the where parameter.

For instance, this URI works fine:

https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/{my-table}/features?version=published&key={my-key}&select=StoreID,"Store Name"

but this does not:

https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/{my-table}/features?version=published&key={my-key}&select=StoreID,"Store Name"&where=StoreID%3D5435

This may be due to the fact that StoreID is a character string:

```
   "properties": {
"StoreID": "5435",
"Store Name": "BROOKWOOD VILLAGE",
"Street": "614 BROOKWOOD VILLAGE",
"City": "BIRMINGHAM",
"State": "AL",
"ZIP": "35209",
"gx_location": "614 BROOKWOOD VILLAGE ,BIRMINGHAM ,AL,35209",
"Country": "US",
"field_9": "FUL",
"field_10": "12",
"gx_id": "1"
```

}

but none of the following formats seem to work for the 'where' parameter either:

```
&where=StoreID%3D"5435"
&where=StoreID%3D\"5435\"
&where=StoreID%3D%225435%22
```

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use single-quotes(`%27`) in the where-clause:

```
&where=StoreID%3D%275435%27
```

Sample: https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709/features?select=Postcode,%22Locality%22&where=Postcode%3d%275606%27&version=published&key=yourKey

Comment: First off, thanks! Second, I see that the specs supposedly allow double-quotes around fields with embedded blanks, so the select clause would allow (per your example) ...select=Postcode,"Locality"...